# Русские символы pdfparser

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once('pdfparser-0.14.0/vendor/autoload.php');

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('TEST.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;

?>
```

Ссылка на тестовый PDF:
https://mega.nz/#!6yRE1CSC!VvZ7vimkVLk4JDVLU9KrtEeZW9jQeKJn98BStl7JN3s

Получаю в ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может у вас проблема с именно в этом pdf-файле? Я только что установил эту либу, работает исправно. UPD: И ещё есть отличия в подключении - вы  подключаете библиотеку строкой `require_once('pdfparser-0.14.0/vendor/autoload.php');`, а в доке написано `include 'vendor/autoload.php';`. Ну я для полной уверенности дописал константу, и у меня при вот таком подключении эта библиотека исправно работает _(проверял на нескольких разных pdf-файлах)_: `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Если присмотреться к "абракадабре", то станет понятно что это русские буквы, слова и предложения, просто криво написаны

Comment: А на другом PDF-файле такая же картина?

Comment: Я не пробовал на другом, но и задача просмотреть именно этот PDF

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал другой файл открыть... А если другой файл отобразится норм, то можно будет попробовать "проблемный файл" преобразовать в *.doc, а из дока обратно в pdf, и попробовать открыть уже новый файл в этой библиотеке.